# How to add defect tab in extent reports

Tags: extentreports

I want to add Bug tab in my extent report as shown in the below screenshot,i am not able to find proper tutorial for this,can someone please help

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbGWM.png)

Answer (score 0):

This tab is added automatically once you log an exception. Example:

```
test.fail(new RuntimeException("msg"));
```

Please refer to the documentation for details.

Comment: Hi Anshoo,which version of extent reports supports bug tab,currently i am using 2.41.2 and it's not displayed

Comment: It should in this version as well.. but since version 2 is no longer supported, would recommend upgrading to 3.